# How to create a HTML document DOM object from code?

Tags: javascript, dom

Currently I'm doing this:

```
var newdoc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("Wrong title");
newdoc.open();
newdoc.write('<!doctype html><html><head><title>Right title</title></head><body><div id="a_div">Right content</div></body></html>');
newdoc.close();
```

And then I try to get some info about the document loaded, for example:

```
> newdoc.title
Right title
> newdoc.getElementById("a_div").innerHTML
Right content
```

The issue is that it only works in Chrome. On Firefox and Opera the DOM does not seem to be loaded after document close. What am I doing wrong?

I wrote this little fiddle to demonstrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/uHz2m/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMImplementation.createHTMLDocument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after reading the docs I noticed `createHTMLDocument()` does not create a zero byte-length document object but a basic HTML scaffolding like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Wrong title</title>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

That's why `newdoc.write()` does not work as expected.

Instead, I can just take the `html` element and change its HTML code ([corrected fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5DmHS/)).

```
var newdoc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("Wrong title");
newdoc.documentElement.innerHTML = '\
   <!doctype html>\
   <html>\
     <head>\
       <title>Right title</title>\
     </head>\
     <body>\
       <div id="a_div">Right content</div>\
     </body>\
   </html>';
```